# C++ Functional Composition - Compose Methods Optimisation

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I have written my own compose method which works fine for PODs how can optimise this for handling user defined types which are expensive to copy?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
std::function<V(T&&)> compose(std::function<V(U)> f, std::function<U(T)> g)
{
    std::function<V(T&&)> result = [&](T&& value){
        return f(g(value));
    };
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    std::function<int(int)> f = [](int v){ return v + 1;};
    std::function<int(int)> g = [](int v){ return v + 2;};

    std::function<int(int)> h = compose(f, g);

    std::cout << "compose(f,g): " << (h(5)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Blair

Comment: POD != expensive to copy. Some PODs are huge, some user-defined types can be copied very cheaply (e.g. only own an integer), and some user-defined types are expensive to copy but cheap to move. So perhaps a better question would be: How do I choose the (likely) fastest to pass a given type, and I think I've seen that one before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I let the C++ compiler decide whether to pass-by-value or pass-by-reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408423/can-i-let-the-c-compiler-decide-whether-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is `boost::call_traits<T>`...